# oledb stored procedure c# Procedure or function expects parameter which was not supplied

Tags: oledb

I am getting the error : Implicit conversion from data type nvarchar to varbinary is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.
my c# code snippet is:

```
 OleDbCommand spCmd = new OleDbCommand
                    ("[SomeServer].[dbo].GetAllProperties", conn)
                    {
                        CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                    };
                spCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P1", path);
                spCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P5", 4);
                int rowsAffected = spCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

path is a string.
corresponding sql sp is:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAllProperties]
@P1 nvarchar (425),
@P2 varchar(32) = NULL,
@P3 as varbinary(85) = NULL, 
@P4 as nvarchar(260) = NULL,
@P5 int
AS
BEGIN
```

....
 Please let me know how to invoke this sp from c#.
i tried specifying all parameters in order as follows but then i get error: Implicit conversion from data type nvarchar to varbinary is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query

```
                spCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P1", path);
                spCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P2", DBNull.Value);
                spCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P3", DBNull.Value);
                spCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P4", DBNull.Value);
                spCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P5", 4);
                int rowsAffected = spCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to pass null values to the optional parameters simply use null instead of DBType.Null. It works:

```
        spCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P1", path);
        spCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P2", null);
        spCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P3", null);
        spCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P4", null);
        spCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P5", 24);
```

Answer (score 1):

Default parameters are ONLY used when they are not present, in other words do NOT add them to the parameter list.

Comment: if i remove the default parameters i get the error:" Procedure or function 'GetAllProperties' expects parameter '@AuthType', which was not supplied." even though i can see it in the parameters of the command object

Comment: OLEDB parameters are order sensitive...  try organizing order to match order of SPROC.

Comment: Well you should keep the order in sync with oledb, can you make the AuthType parameter come before the OwnerSid?  That way you could provide a value for everything but the last 2 parameters (OwnerSid,OwnerName).   If this was ADO.NET there wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: why are you saying OwnerSid? Do you mean i change the order like    Path, AuthType, EditSessionID,
OwnerSid,OwnerName and try? I am not allowed to change this existing SP, isnt there any other way?

Comment: okay if you can't change order...  so you have tried adding the parameters in the same order and for the parameters that have no value (but have a NULL default) use DbNull.VALUE?

Comment: if i use dbnull.value and supply all parameters i get the error:  Implicit conversion from data type nvarchar to varbinary is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query

Comment: ok, are you sure the problem is calling the sproc?  It sounds like there might be an issue executing... have you tried executing from mgmt studio with params and taking c# out of the equation?

Comment: yes it runs fine in SQL ran the following query: `EXEC [ReportServer].[dbo].[GetAllProperties]
  @P1 = N'somepath',
  @P5 = 23`

Comment: Correction: If i change the order of the parameters of sql sp to make P1 and P5 as the first 2 parameters followed by the default parameters the oledbcommand is getting executed successfully. But i dont have the option of modifying the SP.

Comment: you can't use ADO?  SqlClient.Connection object?

Comment: this application is written using oledb, so i can try adding ADO newly but iledb would have been preferable. its not possible in oledb?

Comment: you have to figure out how to add params with a NULL, I personally prefer sproc defaults that are non null, like empty string etc...

Comment: marked ur ans as useful.. plz lemme know how to give u points